# Android Firestore add Item to array inside a Document

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

i need to add an item to an array which is inside a document. Unfortunately my code overwrites always the existing array.
Here is my Code:

```
   db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    Map<String, Object> docData = new HashMap<>();


    docData.put("channelAbos", Arrays.asList("Bla", "Blo"));


    db.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .set(docData, SetOptions.merge());
```

Comment: Did you read and understand the answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029956/android-firestore-add-item-to-array-inside-a-document) you asked a little while ago?  You will need to use FieldValue.arrayUnion

Comment: could you explain it more in detail. My previous question was about HashMap and now its about array .

Comment: So do you really have two different questions here, one for array type document fields and one for object type document fields?